# gmmktime(): You should be using the time() function instead

Tags: php, time

What is the reason of the following error? How to solve the issue?

```
gmmktime(): You should be using the time() function instead
```

The issue in the line number 90:

```
 89         date_default_timezone_set("GMT");
 90         $time = gmmktime();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[gmmktime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmmktime.php) internally uses [mktime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) , which  throws an E_STRICT notice when called with no arguments, so use the [time()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) function instead.

Answer (score 4):

This is a comment from [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmmktime.php)

> gmmktime() should ONLY be used to create a timestamp when specifying a
>   specific GMT date and time.
>
> If you want to make a valid time stamp for the current date & time,
>   use mktime() instead.
>
> UNIX timestamps, by definition, store the GMT time relative to the
>   UNIX epoch.
>
> gmmktime() (without any parameters specified) will effectively use the
>   computer's LOCAL time values just the same as if they were explicit
>   parameters, and the resulting time stamp will be incorrect.  (The
>   resulting timestamp will actually be offset in the OPPOSITE direction
>   of the local timezone offset from GMT!)

So it requires input. You should consider this function as a conversion mechanism rather than a source of formatted data.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that your host may have updated php.

If you ask your host provider to edit your php.ini file, to disable logging of STRICT warnings in, php.ini, you may be sorted.

Also according to [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmmktime.php)
`gmmktime()` internally uses `mktime()` so only times valid in derived local time can be used.

Also check the change log there, it says

As of PHP 5.1.0, the `is_dst` parameter became deprecated. As a result, the new timezone handling features should be used instead.

Comment: We intentionally added STRICT. We don't want to change it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `gmmktime()` and `mktime()` require input, i.e. they take year, month, day, etc and give a timestamp. If you just want the current timestamp use the `time()` function.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for this purpose: `gmdate( 'U' )`